# Merge [google-analytics-android] and [google-analytics-v4] into [google-analytics-firebase]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The current accepted tag for Google Analytics mobile questions is [google-analytics-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-v4). It has 438 questions.

Its description is:

> Google Analytics is a free analytics solution provided by Google, featuring several client-side APIs for data collection. This tag is used for the Collection protocol specifically for Android and iOS SDKs versions 4.

I just ran across a new one that was created [google-analytics-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-android) with 44 questions, so I attempted to create a synonym for it. However, since only moderators are able to create version specific synonyms, I am posting this on Meta.

Note that v4 has been the standard version going on for 5 years now. As a Google Developer expert for Google Analytics, I am not aware of any development on a new version of this, but if I was I would probably be under NDA and couldn't post that here.

Several years ago, Google released [Google analytics reporting api v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) which is an upgrade for the Google Analytics core reporting API v3.

Google has also stopped supporting the old Android and IOS SDK versions 4 and are **now** pushing [Google Analytics firebase](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/android/) and [Google Analytics Firebase IOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/ios/).

As you may expect, the old [google-analytics-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-v4) tag is causing a lot of confusion now. People are using it to tag questions related to [Google analytics reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) which they should just be using [google-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-api).

In order to clean up these issues I would like to suggest a new tag called [google-analytics-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-firebase) where all of the [google-analytics-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-v4) should point to as they are all related to the old mobile stuff.

The only other option would be create a new tag [google-analytics-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-mobile) and point all of [google-analytics-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-v4) to that. Then I will create [google-analytics-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-firebase) and start manually retagging stuff with that, as they come as everything Google analytics mobile related form now on should be Firebase related unless someone is doing something special and completely unsupported.

I would love to hear opinions on how to clean up this tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is now complete:

1. I renamed the tag [google-analytics-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-v4) to [google-analytics-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-firebase).
2. I added [google-analytics-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-android) as a synonym for [google-analytics-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-v4). That is [google-analytics-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-firebase) (× 440) ← [google-analytics-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-android) (× 45).

There is another [google-analytics-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-sdk) which seems to be related to these two tags, but that is for another day.