# Rename [google-drive-sdk] to [google-drive-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I would like to request another [google-*] tag renaming.

The [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) tag is the tag that is currently used for the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk).

While I dont want to turn this into a discussion about API vs SDK, the term on the Google website is [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk).

I believe we can avoid a lot of confusion and miss tagging if we rename this.

Part of the issue will be the same problem we had with the [YouTube*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380980/1841839) tag clean up from a few months ago.   `Google-drive-api` is already a synonym on `Google-drive-sdk`.

[image]

Comment: why not just [google-drive]?

Comment: @DanielA.White to prevent users from asking general computing questions related to [google-drive].

Comment: because all of the other Google api tags end in API and while the Google drive web application isn't programming related it would cause confusion.    YouTube-api Google-sheets-api Google-analitics-api ..... we are taking about API questions it should be google-drive-api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834763/difference-between-an-api-and-sdk

Comment: And people ask [really weird questions in the artificial-intelligence tag](https://twitter.com/BhargavHS/status/1131798635669098498), @Camilo. We really can't prevent people from asking wrong questions completely, but reduce it. I'm looking for a better word too, but prevent seems fine.

Comment: @DaImTo I disagree that [tag:google-drive] isn't programming related. Yes, it's not a code editor but it has features that are relevant for programming like storing files, file sharing settings of files used for programming, quotas, among other things that are could be managed directly over the UI / without using any API.

Comment: @BhargavRao would you mind answering this so that i can mark it accepted.  Since i suspect you handled the rename on this one like that last one :)  I would also like to call this one to your attention its been hanging around for a while so i did an update on it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368081/1841839

Comment: Looks like the other post needs some more discussion? Let me know once there is a decision there, and I can take care of the retag/rename/merge side of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym between the drive-api tag and drive-sdk was first requested back in 2014 in this meta post [Google-Drive related tag synonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266532/google-drive-related-tag-synonyms). A few months later, in Oct 2014, [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api) was added as a synonym for [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) (originally proposed in that direction by Dan McGrath). Since then it has been synonymized in that direction.

Given that it was just a synonym and the tags were not merged, adding [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) as the synonym of [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api),  wasn't possible because [google-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) was already a synonym for [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk) (and we cannot have synonym chains). Therefore I just merged both the tags, and swapped the synonym. The situation now is:

[google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api) ← [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk)
[google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api) ← [google-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive)

Comment: TBH I would have left Google drive as there may be a few rare occasions where a Google-drive tag may be valid.   That being said most of them end up being close voted as off topic and the author pointed to Stack web applications.   Thanks again for the clean up